# How can I extract the unique values of a variable and their counts in SAS

Tags: sas, frequency, datastep

Suppose I have these data read into SAS:

[image: Raw Data]

I would like to list each unique name and the number of months it appeared in the data above to give a data set like this:

[image: Frequency Data]

I have looked into PROC FREQ, but I think I need to do this in a DATA step, because I would like to be able to create other variables within the new data set and otherwise be able to manipulate the new data.

Comment: Your last sentence makes it impossible to give a good answer to this question. Without knowing what further stats you want it's impossible to say what the best method is. You could use PROC MEANS/SQL/FREQ/TABULATE/SUMMARY/REPORT and of course, a data step to count numbers.

Comment: Oh...I forgot hash tables, IML, DS2...and probably some other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Data step:

```
proc sort data=have;
  by name month;
  run;

  data want;
     set have;
     by name month;
     m=month(lag(month));
     if first.id then months=1;
     else if month(date)^=m then months+1;
     if last.id then output;
     keep name months;
run;
```

Pro Sql:

```
proc sql;
   select distinct name,count(distinct(month(month))) as months from have group by name;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to do this in a data step, you wouldn't; you'd use `proc freq` or similar.  Almost every PROC can give you an output dataset (rather than just print to the screen).

```
PROC FREQ data=sashelp.class;
  tables age/out=age_counts noprint;
run;
```

Then you can use this output dataset (`age_counts`) as a `SET` input to another data step to perform your further calculations.

Comment: Thanks; this turned out to be the easiest.  I hadn't realized it was possible to get a dataset out of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `proc sql` to group the variable and count how many are in that group. It might be faster than `proc freq` depending on how large your data is.

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table counts as
    select AGE, count(*) as AGE_CT from sashelp.class 
    group by AGE;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a data step, you can use a Hash Object to hold the counted values:

```
data have;
do i=1 to 100;
    do V = 'a', 'b', 'c';
        output;
    end;
end;
run;

data _null_;
set have end=last;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash cnt();
    rc = cnt.definekey('v');
    rc = cnt.definedata('v','v_cnt');
    rc = cnt.definedone();
    call missing(v_cnt);
end;

rc = cnt.find();
if rc then do;
    v_cnt = 1;
    cnt.add();
end;
else do;
    v_cnt = v_cnt + 1;
    cnt.replace();
end;

if last then
    rc = cnt.output(dataset: "want");
run;
```

This is very efficient as it is a single loop over the data.  The `WANT` data set contains the key and count values.